# Uploading image file through jQuery with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image-uploading, uploading

I have been trying to upload an image to my server from jQuery to PHP, but the uploaded content is always invalid image. I could not identify the error whether I was encoding or decoding it wrong. How can I fix this?

#### jQuery code

```js
$("input[type=file]").change(function(event) {
  $.each(event.target.files, function(index, file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      var object = {};
      object.filename = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]['name'];;
      object.data = encodeURI(event.target.result);
      object.filetype = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]['type'];
      files.push(object);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});

$("form").submit(function(form) {
  $.each(files, function(index, file) {
    $.ajax({url: "handle.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {fileName: file.filename, data: file.data, fileType: file.filetype},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#data').html(data);
            }
    });
  });
  files = [];
  form.preventDefault();
});
```

#### PHP code

```php
if (isset($_POST["data"]) || isset($_POST["fileName"])) {
    $data = $_POST["data"];
    $fileName = $_POST["fileName"];
    $fileType = $_POST["filetype"];

    $replace = "data:" . $fileType . ";base64,";
    $filedata = str_replace($replace, "", $data); // echo $filedata;
    $decodedData = urldecode($filedata); // echo $decodedData;

    $fp = fopen('uploads/' . $fileName, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Why sending `base64` encoded stuff meant for just preview why not send original files (of file control) using `formData`?

Comment: @Novice The problem is I want to handle multiple files and the user might chose a file and then remove it before he uploads the file, and its not possible to remove a file from the original $_FILE['file'].

Comment: Yes i agree, added an answer below

Comment: Don't understand your problem with [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)... It's faster and ~9 times better then base64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you get the [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) code on the server. For example, you can echo, etc.

Then assuming your image Base64 code was in $_POST['image']:

```
$data = $_POST['image']
$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);

$data = base64_decode($data); // Base64 decoded image data

$source_img = imagecreatefromstring($data);

$imageSave = imagejpeg($source_img, $file, 10);

imagedestroy($source_img);
```

Using the above lines you can save the image as a file from Base64.

Comment: What does this: `str_replace(' ', '+', $data)` do? And there's no need to do the whole `imagecreatefromstring()`, `imagejpeg()` and `imagedestroy()`. After the base64_decode, you can just save the image content to file.

Comment: removed that line. It was extra for removing credential white spaces. but good catch it should not be there.

Comment: I echo the $_POST['data'] from jquery and it gets to the server , still my image is invalid.

Comment: You did add this line

Comment: $data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);

Comment: did you echo your file type?

Comment: in your change event in js do it this way.

Comment: var FR= new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
        object.data =  e.target.result;
    };       
    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );

Comment: But the imagecreateform was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery do it this way:

```
$.each(event.target.files, function(index, file) {
    var FR = new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
        object.data = e.target.result; };
        FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
    FR.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

What I see is the you are encoding it wrongly in this line

```
object.data = encodeURI(event.target.result);
```

Comment: I don't think that will compile. There are two `{`s and three `}`s.

Answer (score 0):

A few small mistakes, otherwise it's almost working.

In `reader.onload` you are using `document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]['name'];` which would select only the first file (see the constant `files[0]`). So instead of manually searching you can use `file` parameter of `each` loop to get filename and type:

```
var files = [];
$("input[type=file]").change(function(event) {
  $.each(event.target.files, function(index, file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      var object = {};
      object.filename = file.name;
      object.data = encodeURI(event.target.result);
      object.filetype = file.type;
      files.push(object);
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});
```

In PHP code, a small mistake:

```
$fileType = $_POST["filetype"]; // <-- small "t"
```

`urldecode` cannot decode [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). For that, use `base64_decode`:

```
$decodedData = base64_decode($filedata); // echo $decodedData;
```